# wpf chart-binding data from wcf

Tags: wcf, wpftoolkit

i have created pie chart in wpf in need to bind data from database to this pie chart from wcf how to write code in the wcf and bind it to this pie chart of wpf.

i'm new to wpf and wcf.

Can any1 help me on this

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to "paint" data from wcf you should expose a WCF service to return an object with these data.

Then it depends on the kind of pie chart you have build... you could build a pie chart that only receives this object and paints it... So you could have a ViewModel with this object and bind you pie chart to it.

Let me now if you need more especific help.

Comment: if you can send me any sample program examples it will be helpful or any link

Comment: I don't really know what examples do you need... tutorials about WCF? WPF?

Comment: That's really big... here you have a WCF example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCF-Service-Create-Config.aspx and here a WPF pie chart example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PieChartDataBinding.aspx

Comment: here they have explained about hoe to bind xml data to datagridview but i needed hoe bind database data to wpf chart...can you provide me some other link..